# Unable to login using cf login in sap cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am getting started to use cloud foundry , i have taken a trial account in SAP Cloud Foundry . I have installed cf cli on my system but unfortunately i am not able to login, whenever i try to login or even try to cf api i get this error:-

Request error: Get https://api.xx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxxxxxx.com/v2/info: dial tcp: i/o timeout
TIP: If you are behind a firewall and require an HTTP proxy, verify the https_proxy environment variable is correctly set. Else, check your network connection.

I have tried setting and unsetting the proxy but it doesn't help.

Any Suggestions?

Vishesh.

Comment: This error means that the CLI was not able to establish a connection with your API endpoint within its timeout period (which defaults to 5 sec). You can set environment variable CF_DIAL_TIMEOUT to e.g. 10 to see if that makes a difference. If not, then it's possible that there is another reason preventing the CLI to reach the endpoint, such as a wrong proxy setting, API endpoint, faulty DNS server or a firewall in between not letting connections through.
There are various things to try to investigate, one being to `curl` your API domain with `-v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening as SAP CF is not available publicly and requires you to configure special proxy settings over.

You can check for SAP cloud foundry JAM Page for more information.